# Why sudo user can use sched_setscheduler SCHED_RR while root can not?

Tags: linux, sudo, root, scheduling, privileges

I am running Arch Linux on a Raspberry Pi 2.

I have a user-space program that uses Gordon's `wiringPi` library and, in particular, the [`piHiPri()` function](http://wiringpi.com/reference/priority-interrupts-and-threads/) that attempts to set the highest priority for the current process (using [`sched_setscheduler`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) and `SCHED_RR` mode).
This function needs superuser privileges.

The root user is the default one when installing Arch Linux so I created a user named `builder` that I added to `sudoers` thanks to `visudo`.

My problem is:
when I execute the program with the `root` user, the `sched_setscheduler` function returns “Operation not permitted” (getting it from `errno`).

If I execute it while being `builder` I get a “permission denied”.

However if I execute it with `sudo myProgram` while being `builder`, everything is fine and I can see that priority has changed with the `top` command.

I thought that the `root` user might not have UID 0 so I checked with `id -u root` but this returns 0.

`ls -l myProgramm` gives `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root`. I also tried to set SUID with `chmod +s myProgramm` without success.

Any idea on how to make my program executable by root?

**EDIT:**

As Gilles advised I ran `ulimit -r` and it returned 0 in any cases (`builder`and `root`).

I changed a line in `/etc/security/limits.conf` from: `*    -    rtprio     0`

To : `*    -    rtprio     99`

This affected the output of `ulimit -r` as expected: it returns now 99.

I then tried again to run my program with `root` but I still have the same `Operation not permitted` error **and now** it does not work anymore with `sudo` (same `Operation not permitted`as above)... strange !

While investigating I reverted back to old `/etc/security/limits.conf` settings.

Answer (score 4):

I also got hit by this problem. In my case it turned out that docker daemon has reconfigured default cgroups. As a result root user had cgroup slice with `cpu.rt_runtime_us` set to zero. In order to set real-time scheduler (either RR or FIFO) you need to have some CPU time assigned. If your process does not have it (when `cpu.rt_runtime_us` is zero), you will get "permission denied".

More details about cgroups and docker related to this problem are in this error report at RedHat Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1467919

Answer (score 2):

One thing that could explain the difference is if you're ending up with different limits for the maximum realtime priority (`ulimit -r`). Root cannot exceed the limit, but can raise it. Check with `ulimit -r` (or, in C, with `getrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, …)` and raise the limit before running your program if necessary.

If that doesn't help, it's probably a problem in your program, rather than a problem in your system configuration. Post a [small but self-contained source code that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (programming is off-topic on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)).